# Shebang line limit in bash and linux kernel

Tags: linux, bash, shebang

I'm trying to execute python scripts automatically generated by zc.buildout so I don't have control over them.  My problem is that the shebang line (#!) is too long for either bash (80 character limit) or direct execution (some Linux kernel constant I don't know).

This is an example script to help you reproduce my problem:

```
#!/././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././bin/bash
echo Hola!
```

How can be bash or the kernel configured to allow for bigger shebang lines?

Comment: If you pass the script as an argument to the interpreter (`bash x.sh` rather than `./x.sh`) the shebang line would just be ignored as a comment and should not affect the execution.

Comment: I know, the problem is that I'm not the one invoking those scripts either...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Limited to 127 chars on 99.9% of systems due to kernel compile time buffer limit.

It's limited in the kernel by `BINPRM_BUF_SIZE`, set in `include/linux/binfmts.h`.

Comment: See also `man execve`: "A maximum line length of 127 characters is allowed for the first line in a #! executable shell script."

Answer (score 14):

If you don't want to recompile your kernel to get longer shebang lines, you could write a wrapper:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "usage: ${0##*/} script [args ...]"
    exit
fi

# we're going to expand a variable *unquoted* to use word splitting, but
# we don't want to have path expansion effects, so turn that off
set -f

shebang=$(head -1 "$1")
if [[ $shebang == '#!'* ]]; then
    interp=( ${shebang#\#!} )        # use an array in case a argument is there too
else
    interp=( /bin/sh )
fi

# now run it
exec "${interp[@]}" "$@"
```

and then run the script like: `wrapper.sh script.sh`

Comment: +1 Simple workaround that solves all the problems without needing any kernel changes, patches or other hacks.

Answer (score 10):

Updated @glenn jackman's script to support passing in command line arguments.

Incidentally, I ran into this problem when creating a python virtualenv inside of a very deep directory hierarchy.

In my case, this was a virtualenv created inside a Mesos framework dir.

The extra long shebang rendered calling `xxx/.../venv/bin/pip` useless.

The wrapper script proved most useful.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

script="$1" 
shebang=$(head -1 "$script")

# use an array in case a argument is there too
interp=( ${shebang#\#!} )        

# now run it, passing in the remaining command line arguments
shift 1
exec "${interp[@]}" "$script" "${@}"
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you're using this script with the virtual env? Our build fails during the initial creation of the virtual env because the #! path to easy_install is too long already.