# import: command not found with python 3.5

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, centos

I'm looking some clues or solutions to fix below weird problem.

```
[sc-d02-087-017:~]$ cat mytest.py
#!/build/toolchain/lin64/python-3.5.1/bin/python
import platform, sys
print(platform.system())
sys.exit(0)
```

I'm trying to run my test program as shell executable, but shell not recognizing that its a python program that has to interpreted by given /build/toolchain/lin64/python-3.5.1/bin/python, instead throwing err.

```
[sc-d02-087-017:~]$ ./mytest.py
./mytest.py: line 2: import: command not found
./mytest.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `platform.system'
./mytest.py: line 3: `print(platform.system())'
```

But this works as expected with python prompt and/or as command line

```
[sc-d02-087-017:~]$ /build/toolchain/lin64/python-3.5.1/bin/python -c 'import platform, sys;print(platform.system());'
Linux
```

my machine is 64 arch based

```
[sc-d02-087-017:~]$ uname -a
Linux sc-d02-087-017 2.6.18-308.8.1.el5 #1 SMP Tue May 29 14:57:25 EDT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

As requested in the comments:

```
[sc-d02-087-017:~]$ xxd mytest.py | head
0000000: 2321 2f62 7569 6c64 2f74 6f6f 6c63 6861 #!/build/toolcha
0000010: 696e 2f6c 696e 3634 2f70 7974 686f 6e2d in/lin64/python-
0000020: 332e 352e 312f 6269 6e2f 7079 7468 6f6e 3.5.1/bin/python
0000030: 332e 350a 696d 706f 7274 2070 6c61 7466 3.5.import platf
0000040: 6f72 6d2c 2073 7973 0a70 7269 6e74 2870 orm, sys.print(p
0000050: 6c61 7466 6f72 6d2e 7379 7374 656d 2829 latform.system()
0000060: 290a 7379 732e 6578 6974 2830 290a      ).sys.exit(0).

[sc-d02-087-017:~]$ ls -l mytest.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mmopuru mts 110 Jun 2 17:23 mytest.py
```

Comment: check `/build/toolchain/lin64/python-3.5.1/bin/python`

Comment: checking what? it's existence ? it does, thats why prompt works.

Comment: [sc-d02-087-017:~]$ xxd mytest.py | head
0000000: 2321 2f62 7569 6c64 2f74 6f6f 6c63 6861  #!/build/toolcha
0000010: 696e 2f6c 696e 3634 2f70 7974 686f 6e2d  in/lin64/python-
0000020: 332e 352e 312f 6269 6e2f 7079 7468 6f6e  3.5.1/bin/python
0000030: 332e 350a 696d 706f 7274 2070 6c61 7466  3.5.import platf
0000040: 6f72 6d2c 2073 7973 0a70 7269 6e74 2870  orm, sys.print(p
0000050: 6c61 7466 6f72 6d2e 7379 7374 656d 2829  latform.system()
0000060: 290a 7379 732e 6578 6974 2830 290a       ).sys.exit(0).

Comment: @MuraliMopuru: What is the output of `/build/toolchain/lin64/python-3.5.1/bin/python ./mytest.py`?

Comment: [sc-d02-087-017:~]$ /build/toolchain/lin64/python-3.5.1/bin/python mytest.py
Linux

Comment: What do you get from `file /build/toolchain/lin64/python-3.5.1/bin/python`?

Comment: I humbly submit that your `xxd` output does not match your `cat` output. In particular - an extra `3.5` appears in the `xxd` output. I believe your shebang line is incorrect and actually reads `#!/build/toolchain/lin64/python-3.5.1/bin/python3.5` which probably points to a file that does not exist.  Therefore, your file is being interpreted as a shell script, hence the error that you see.  If this turns out to be the case, let me know and I'll post a proper answer for the bounty :) (cc @billlynch)

Comment: Nice spot @JRichardSnape!  I looked at exactly that possibility, but despite checking twice, couldn't see it...  Damnit!  :-)

Comment: Does the command `namei /build/toolchain/lin64/python-3.5.1/bin/python3.5` reveal anything interesting?

Comment: @Richard, plz post your answer to accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are aware, the error message is because your python script is being interpreted directly as a shell script.

Usually this happens when you have no "shebang" line (`!#/path/to/python/executable`).  As this does not apply, I looked a bit harder and noticed that your `xxd` output does not match your `cat` output. In particular - an extra `3.5` appears in the `xxd` output. I believe your shebang line is incorrect and actually reads `#!/build/toolchain/lin64/python-3.5.1/bin/python3.5` which probably points to a file that is not the one you thought / does not exist. Therefore, your file is being interpreted as a shell script, hence the error that you see.

***However*** I would expect a non-existent file to give an error like:

> ```
> bad interpreter: No such file or directory
> ```

therefore I wonder if your error is more subtle than that, in that your `#!` line is pointing somewhere other that you think, but that it still points to a valid executable.

***N.B.*** A test you could do, but which does not appear in your question is to run

```
/build/toolchain/lin64/python-3.5.1/bin/python ./mytest.py
```

If that works the same as

```
/build/toolchain/lin64/python-3.5.1/bin/python -c 'import platform, sys;print(platform.system());'
```

then you almost certainly have a problem/typo in your `#!` line.

Answer (score 0):

I get a wide range of similar issues by saving the python 3 file with different encodings from UTF8 (e.g. UTF16), so I suspect that's your problem. Try making sure it is saved with a "normal" encoding (UTF8) and perhaps that will fix it!

If it does, I suspect that the "problem" is that python3 has much better support for differently encoded files... bash does not it seems :-).

Answer (score 0):

Your shebang line may be [too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813538/shebang-line-limit-in-bash-and-linux-kernel) for your system. Try shortening it. For example, create a symlink to `/build/toolchain/lin64/python-3.5.1`:

```
ln -s /build/toolchain/lin64/python-3.5.1 /tmp/xyz
```

and change the shebang line to `#!/tmp/xyz/bin/python`. If that fixes the problem, then you can choose a more proper short way of referring to your build of python.

Answer (score 0):

try to add that path to you profile /build/toolchain/lin64/python-3.5.1/bin/python & execution path file either .bash_profile or depening on the shell you use, then switch user to the same login or execute the profile like . ./.bash_profile and try agin with your script....hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea why you used `./`.

Execute Python script like this:

```
python mytest.py        # and then just hit enter.
```

If that doesn't work then just let me know.

Comment: The OP wants to know why ./ doesn't work. He has specified the interpreter on the first line with the #! so the script should run the program automatically in python when called using ./. If he uses python mytest.py this will explicitly call the python interpreter and the first line is redundant

Comment: your answer is right i do not know why they downvote it?!?!?!